# Table for Invoice

Tags: tables, invoice

How I can realize a table like that in the picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{lccc}

                \toprule

                \midrule

                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you really ask for? Your approach misses the `booktabs` package, but the rest is just LaTeX-table-work. For the empty line use `\\[\baselineskip]`.

Comment: Ok, but it is small... How I can to do this so large? @TeXnician

Comment: Just use a `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lccc}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular table you could do this...

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcrr}
\toprule
\textbf{Descrizione}&\textbf{Ore}&\textbf{Prezzo Ora}&\textbf{Totole}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Consulting Services}&&&\\
Realizzazione Sito Web&40.00 hours&\EURdig12.00&\EURdig480.00\\\hline
\textbf{Subtotale}&\textbf{40.00 hours}&&\textbf{\EURhv480.00}\\
&&&\\
\textbf{Hosting}&&&\\
Web Hosting&&\EURdig25.00&\EURdig35.00\\
\bottomrule
\textbf{Totale (Ritenuta inclusia)}&&&\textbf{\EURhv505.00}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

However, I would recommend looking at the `invoice` package if you plan on making many invoices. [link](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/invoice/doc/invoice.pdf)

Note: I used `r` instead of `c` since the columns in the photo are aligned to the right, not the center.